# Laravel queue fails

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue, forge

I'm using `Laravel forge` and I've setup a `queue` called `mail`. It handles all mails in my application. When I set the `QUEUE_DRIVER` to `sync` in my `.env` file all mails are being send as expected. But when I use the `QUEUE_DRIVER=beanstalkd` mails do not send.

When I listen for the queue `php artisan queue:work --queue=mail` I can see that the jobs are being handled.

Already restarted the `queue` and `recreated` it. But nothing seems to work. When I look into my `jobs` table there are no errors. What on earth could be going on?

Comment: Please restart the `queue` and then check you `laravel.log` for errors...